# having a .html page as a view in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'd like to have the view to be rendered when calling into a controller action be the contents of a .html file in a specific directory inside this same web app.  This is because all of the content that is provided to the browser is served up from .html pages that have had no processing whatsoever by the server, but I'd like for the "/" content path of the app to force the user to view a login page if they have not been authenticated.  If the browser were to put the full path of the index.html or even the login .html into the url they'd be able to view it, but the data that's gotten (via ajax calls) to populate the html content on the client side would still not be available because the user isn't authenticated.  Am I making sense?

What I'd like is something that might look similar to:

```
public class LoginController {
  public ActionResult Index() {
    return HtmlView("~/rawPages/login.html");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to:

> I'd like for the "/" content path of the app to force the user to view
>   a login page if they have not been authenticated

for that, all you have to do is use the "location" tag in you web.config (the following exampley denies acces to SomePage.html for anonymous users:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="SomePage.html">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

If this is really your purpose, then you do not need to configure that html "as a view"